# Page can not be displayed Error after Creating Site Collection in SP 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

Am working on SP 2010. I created a site collection and when I navigate to the site (`http://srvr1:333/sites/demo`) I am getting error

> This page can't be displayed

Where exactly I need to check for fixing this issue?

The same issue occurs when I created a new site collection within the 80 port also.Even the root site of 80 port also doesn't work

Comment: You can check in the Event Logs of the server. And Instead of using Central Admin use Powershell script to create a site collection and see if you get same error..

Comment: Dou you have a DNS record or host file entry for the root site? Guessing your are not routed to the correct place.

Comment: No, I dont have a  DNS record or host file entry. its my desktop where Win 7 is installed and simply followed the instructions for SP 2010 install.

Answer (score 1):

couple of things.

1. Verify that the web site is in IIS.
2. Verify that the web site Virtual Folder exists in Inetpub
3. Check if you have more than one web application on the same port. (If yes, use AAM and IIS Host headers to resolve conflicts)
4. you mentioned windows 7, did you created the VM or install on win7? Disable Loopback check.
5. check the ULS logs
6. Also try to add the site into Browser's trusted site.